# Usage of the word duplicate

Tags: grammar

Consider the following dataset
1, 1, 1, 2, 3

- Would you have one duplicate because one value has duplicates?
- two duplicates because there are 2 duplicated values?
- or three duplicates because the same value occurs 3 times?

If you then remove the duplicate values would you have removed 1 duplicate or 2 duplicates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say there are **two** duplicates in the set, but I would also say that I am using the word *duplicates* here to mean *duplicate values*.

The word *duplicate* can take on [several meanings](https://www.wordnik.com/words/duplicate); one that fits well in this discussion is:

> **duplicate** (*n.*) One of two or more things corresponding in every respect to each other.

One dictionary adds a pertinent usage note:

> **duplicate** (*adj.*) being the same as another; identical. `This may exclude the first identical item in a series, but usage is inconsistent.`

In other words, the first 1 in your dataset would be **not** be counted as a duplicate, but the next two would be – yet the dictionary acknowledges that this is not a hard-and-fast, immutable rule with no wiggle room for alternate interpretations.

That said, I think it's safe to say that, if you wanted to "remove all the duplicates," you'd remove two members of the set, leaving you with the set {1, 2, 3}.

Answer (score 2):

*Duplicate* is synonymous with *copy*.

If X is duplicated, it means an existing X is used to make a new Y.

Unless this happened with the '1' values in your list, technically they aren't duplicates.  You simply have 3 instances of '1'.

The maximum number of duplicates you can have of '1' is 2, because you would have had to use one to "create" the others.

Comment: No, "duplicate" doesn't mean created from a previous instance. If I print a file out twice, I have duplicate hardcopies, neither of them created from the other.

Comment: You created the duplicate hard*copies* from an original file which is not a copy.

Answer (score 0):

"**Duplicate**" implies exactly two copies - one original and one copy.

To convey the meaning of 3 copies, you should use "**triplicate**".

For more than 3 copies, you should use "**copies**".

**Duplicate** is related to *double*.

**Triplicate** is related to *triple*.

Since you do not use *double* or *triple* for anything bigger than 3, you do not use **duplicate** or **triplicate** for anything bigger than 3, with their respective meanings.

Comment: That is only one meaning of the word. See https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/duplicate